# some problem with variables in objective-c 

Tags: objective-c, ios, variables, memory

Here is what I am doing :

```
    [imageTag.mediaTags addObject:unitTag];
    [imageTag.allTags addObject:unitTag];

    unitTag.title=@"";
    unitTag.link=@"";
    unitTag.description=@"";
    unitTag.price=@"";
    unitTag.imageLink=@"";
```

The problem is, once I make execute beyond line 2, the values stored in the array gets lost too (I used GDB to print and figured that out). Now the thing is, I am reusing the unitTag object to enter some information and saving that information inside an array. So what are my options ? I need to delete the values because some of the values are optional and I dont want to mess up.

Can anyone please kindly let me know ? Thanks.

Comment: Are `imageTag.mediaTags` and `imageTag.allTags` possibly `nil`?

Comment: well, after "addObject" is done I print "objectAtIndex" and get values. and imageTag is a NSMutableArray which is initialized. Its only after executing the last 5 lines that I get <object returned empty description> thingy :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need to make a copy of the UnitTag object and insert that into the array.  You're just storing an object reference in the array and then nuking the values the reference is using.

`addObject` is not storing a copy - it's storing the actual object reference.

To make a copy, you need to create a new object that unitTag is, and then add it.  So potentially your code could be:

```
id unitTagCopy = [unitTag createCopy];
[imageTag.mediaTags addObject:unitTagCopy];
[imageTag.allTags addObject:unitTagCopy];
```

You'd have to add the createCopy method.  I imagine it could be:

```
-(id) createCopy {
    MyObj* obj = [[[MyObj] init] alloc] autorelease];
    obj.title= self.title;
    obj.link= self.link;
    obj.description= self.description;
    obj.price= self.price;
    obj.imageLink= self.imageLink;
    return obj;
}
```

Comment: @SB : how do I do that ? any help ?

Comment: I've updated the answer.  The createCopy method would go in your MyObj.m file.  I'm assuming unitTag is of type MyObj

Comment: Note that there’s a protocol for that: `NSCopying`.

Comment: @SB : thanks...but whats the case when we are copying NSMutableArrays this way ...(and not just plain objects)... do we need create copies again ?